# How to attribute to each elements of a sublist sharing comment elements the unique ID of the related sublist?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, networkx, subgraph

Out of an list of ~500k lines made of pairs of items, I'm trying to build up a file that aims to allocate for each item an ID related to the group they belong to. *Further explanations follow.*

And I would need some help to get the result in a smart and efficient way (that is pythonic)

==============

#### what I want to do

Transform the **input** file df0 into the **desired output** df2

For instance, the starting file would look like this (but with 500k entries), where a relation from item1 to item2 is determined by the structure of the dataframe.

**df0 : input**

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({
"item 1": ['Q', 'R', 'B', 'A'],
"item 2": ['R', 'P', 'A', 'C']
})
```

It reads as following: item Q is related to item R, and item R is related to item P, hence item Q is related to item P (same with with A, B and C). In that case, the transitivity of relationships leads to build two groups of items.

- Each item belongs to only 1 group.
- It is expected in the real case file that groups can hold up to 11 items.
- the alphabetic order plays no role

---

Thanks to other contributions on stackoverflow, I managed to group all transitive items into single sets and allocate them a single group number (or ID). Meaning I get a dataframe that looks like that:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
"items": [{'Q', 'R', 'P'}, {'B', 'A', 'C'} ],
"group": [1, 2]
})
```

---

The result above is now to be transformed to support further data post-treatments and the desired outcome should look like this:

**df2 : desired output**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
"items": ['Q', 'R', 'P', 'B', 'A', 'C' ],
"group": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 ]
})
```

==============

#### What I managed so far

**step 1 :** convert df1.item into a series of single items

```
d = df1.item
e = list(sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(d))))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'item':e})
```

**step 2 :** 'vlookup' df2.items back to df1.group via df1.items

```
df2['group'] = ''  

n = 0
for row in df2.items :
m = 0
for row in df1.items :
    if df2['items'][n] in df1['items'][m]:
        df2['group'][n] = df1['group'][m]
    m = m + 1
n = n + 1
```

==============

**It does work for small tables, but is not workable on large dataframes.**

I'm now looking for assistance regarding :

- either a better code for step 2 to enhance df2 *(preferred)*
- or a better way to jump over step 2 and get df2 straight out of df1

*Thank you very in advance for your time and feedback !*

Comment: 1) Is `R` related to `B`?  2) Why do you want to use DataFrames?

Comment: 1) as per df0, R is not related to B. Else we would have only one group.
2) I have no constrains to not use DataFrames, I'm open to alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you might try looking at the [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/) library.

You can create an undirect network graph directly from your [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html) and use the [`connected_component_subgraphs`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs.html) method to extract the subgroups:

```
import networkx as nx

df0 = pd.DataFrame({'item 1': {0: 'Q', 1: 'R', 2: 'B', 3: 'A'},
                    'item 2': {0: 'R', 1: 'P', 2: 'A', 3: 'C'}})

g = nx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist(df0, source='item 1', target='item 2')
```

Use list comprehension to create data for your new `DataFrame`

```
subgroups = [(n, i + 1) for i, sg in enumerate(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(g)) for n in sg.nodes]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(subgroups, columns=['items', 'subgroup'])
print(df2)

  items  subgroup
0     P         1
1     R         1
2     Q         1
3     C         2
4     A         2
5     B         2
```

Comment: **awesome** I just tested in Jupyter with the ~400k lines file and it worked perfectly! thank you very much!

Comment: @ionah happy to help :)